# How to redirect to the post when featured image is clicked?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On my wordpress website in the blog page , Some posts have featured images , On licking on these images they redirect to their path , I want them to redirect to the post link.

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

In the wordpress "have_posts()" loop after "the_post();" (index.php in theme):

```
href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"
```

In the custom loop:

```
href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($single_post->ID)); ?>"
```

where $single_post is an element of posts array